# Blank page is displayed instead of Bootstrap Navbar that I am trying to create with React Router

Tags: javascript, reactjs, bootstrap-4, react-router-dom

I am trying to create a navbar using Bootstrap and React. Even though my code is compiled without any errors the webpage that is rendered is completely blank. Please see my code below for reference:

app.js:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { useState } from "react";
import logo from "./logo.svg";
import { Routes, Route, Link } from "react-router-dom";
import "bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css";
import "./App.css";

import AddReview from "./components/add-review";
import RestaurantlLst from "./components/restaurant-list";
import Restaurants from "./components/restaurants";
import Login from "./components/login";

function App() {
  const [user, setUser] = useState(null);

  async function login(user = null) {
    setUser(user);
  }

  async function logout() {
    setUser(null);
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-dark">
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">
          Restaurant Reviews
        </a>

        <div class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
          <li class="nav-item">
            <Link to={"/restaurants"}>Restaurants</Link>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            {user ? (
              <a
                onClick={logout}
                className="nav-link"
                style={{ cursor: "pointer" }}
              >
                Logout {user.name}
              </a>
            ) : (
              <Link to={"/login"} className="nav-link">
                Login
              </Link>
            )}
          </li>
        </div>
      </nav>

      <div className="container mt-3">
        <Routes>
          <Route
            exact
            path={["/", "/restaurants"]}
            component={RestaurantlLst}
          />

          <Route
            path="/restaurants/:id/review"
            render={(props) => <AddReview {...props} user={user} />}
          />

          <Route
            path="/restaurants/:id"
            render={(props) => <Restaurants {...props} user={user} />}
          />
          <Route
            path="/login"
            render={(props) => <Login {...props} user={user} />}
          />
        </Routes>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

index.js:

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom/client";
import { BrowserRouter } from "react-router-dom";
import App from "./App";

const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById("root"));
root.render(
  <BrowserRouter>
    <App />
  </BrowserRouter>
);
```

All of the components are similar, as given below:

Login component:

```
import React from "react";

function Login() {
  return <div>Login</div>;
}

export default Login;
```

What am I doing wrong ?

Answer (score 0):

The `Route` component API changed in v6, there isn't any `component` or `render` prop now, they were replaced by a single `element` prop taking a `ReactNode`, a.k.a. JSX. The `path` prop now also only takes a single path string, not an array.

```
<Routes>
  <Route
    path="/"
    element={<RestaurantlLst />}
  />
  <Route
    path="/restaurants"
    element={<RestaurantlLst />}
  />
  <Route
    path="/restaurants/:id/review"
    element={<AddReview user={user} />}
  />
  <Route
    path="/restaurants/:id"
    element={<Restaurants user={user} />}
  />
  <Route
    path="/login"
    render={<Login user={user} />}
  />
</Routes>
```

If these components need to access "route props" these also no longer exist. They should use the React hooks that replaced them if they need to access `location`, `params`, etc.

Another way to structure the routes is to use layout and index routes:

Example:

```
<Routes>
  <Route path="/">
    <Route index element={<Navigate to="restaurants" replace />} />
    <Route path="restaurants">
      <Route index element={<RestaurantlLst />} />
      <Route path=":id">
        <Route index element={<Restaurants user={user} />} />
        <Route path="review" element={<AddReview user={user} />} />
      </Route>
    </Route>
  </Route>
  <Route
    path="/login"
    render={<Login user={user} />}
  />
</Routes>
```